# Can an arc of electrons be inhibited with high winds?

Tags: electricity, laser, ideal-gas, aerodynamics, molecular-dynamics

I'm am trying to see if electricity can be transferred efficiently to a battery free E-fan plane. How will wind sheer effect the transfer of electrons through thin air using a laser filamentation electrical discharge method at different wind speeds of orbital speeds and higher? Could enough wind bend a constant discharge in the bottom picture if the laser and electricity stayed constant?

E-plane
[image]

Laser induced electrical discharge.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This really isn't that different from some of your previous questions on the subject. Now, consider the width of the discharge and the flux (wind) of neutrals coming through. How will that impact the requirements for a stable plasma discharge?

Comment: Jen, your page says you are 11th-grade home schooled. Your questions show very high creativity, and very high naivete'. Will you be attending a technical college? If you learn basic calculus and physics from good teachers, and relate it to a real subject like aviation or engineering, it will serve your creativity very well.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey  I'm just trying to recreate the space elevator.

Comment: @sammygerbil what do you think?

Comment: fun question thumbs up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that the laser beam creates a long thin cylindrical zone inside which the atoms are ionized, allowing electrical discharges along the cylinder - along the interior of that cylindrical zone - to happen.

So it must depend on how fast those discharges are. Can they get to the other side - the end of the cylinder, the E-Fan that you want to power - before the air flow of the wind carries the ionized atoms out of the cylindrical zone of ionization created by the laser beam, and into an environment where they will quickly capture free electrons and become neutral and non-conducting again.

I owe the realization that it's just a competition between speed of the discharge electrons along the beam, and speed of the air flow through the beam, to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/103451/1486) on why a candle in the wind goes out, when it talks about the speed of the "flame front".

Comment: So can we call this front the electron flame front for the speed of air, the frequency, intensity and length of ionized gas able to conduct a current?